# Builder pattern with error-checking: is it possible/advisable?

Tags: java, error-handling, builder

I am using the Builder pattern to make it easier to create objects. However, the standard builder pattern examples do not include error-checking, which are needed in my code. For example, the `accessibility` and `demandMean` arrays in the `Simulator` object should have the same length. A brief framework of the code is shown below:

```
public class Simulator {
    double[] accessibility;
    double[] demandMean;

    // Constructor obmitted for brevity

    public static class Builder {
        private double[] _accessibility;
        private double[] _demandMean;

        public Builder accessibility(double[] accessibility) {
            _accessibility = accessiblity.clone();
            return this;
        }

        public Builder demandMean(double[] demandMean) {
            _demandMean = demandMean.clone();
            return this;
        }

        // build() method obmitted for brevity
    }
}
```

As another example, in a promotion optimization problem, there are various promotional vehicles (e.g. flyers, displays) and promotion modes, which are a set of promotional vehicles (e.g. none, flyer only, display only, flyer and display). When I create the `Problem`, I have to define the set of vehicles available, and check that the promotion modes use a subset of these vehicles and not some other unavailable vehicles, as well as that the promotion modes are not identical (e.g. there aren't two promo modes that are both "flyer only"). A brief framework of the code is shown below:

```
public class Problem {
    Set<Vehicle> vehicles;
    Set<PromoMode> promoModes;

    public static class Builder {
        Set<Vehicle> _vehicles;
        Set<PromoMode> _promoModes;
    }
}

public class PromoMode {
    Set<Vehicle> vehiclesUsed;
}
```

My questions are the following:

1. Is there a standard approach to address such a situation?
2. Should the error checking be done in the constructor or in the builder when the `build()` method is called?
3. Why is this the "right" approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need invariants to hold while creating an object then stop construction if any parameter violates the invariants. This is also a fail-fast approach.
The builder pattern helps creating an object when you have a large number of parameters.
That does not mean that you don't do error checking.
Just throw an appropriate `RuntimeException` as soon as a parameter violates the objects invariants

Answer (score 2):

You should use the constructor, since that follows the Single Responsibility Principle better.  It is not the responsibility of the Builder to check invariants. It's only real job is to collect the data needed to build the object.
Also, if you decide to change the class later to have public constructors, you don't have to move that code.

You definitely shouldn't check invariants in setter methods. This has several benefits:
* You only need to do checking ONCE
* In cases such as your code, you CAN'T check your invariants earlier, since you're adding your two arrays at different times.  You don't know what order your users are going to add them, so you don't know which method should run the check.

Unless a setter in your builder does some intense calculations (which is rarely the case - generally, if there's some sort of calculation required, it should happen in the constructor anyway), it doesn't help very much to 'fail early' in, especially since fluent Builders like yours use only 1 line of code to build the object anyway, so any try block would surround that whole line either way.

Answer (score 0):

The "right" approach really depends on the situation - if it is invalid to construct the arrays with different sizes, i'd say it's better to do the handling in the construction, the sooner an invalid state is caught the better.

Now, if you for instance can change the arrays and put in a different one - then it might be better to do it when calling them.